# Why does alternating current change direction?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

As the title implies, I would like to learn why. I have read wikipedia pages in 3 different languages, searched the net and found nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the simplest hint  is that its due to the manner /way in which one produces it.

Comment: "Why" is a very broad category.  Try to narrow your question to some specific behavior or topic  regarding alternating current, and edit.

Comment: @BillN Well, sorry but I am not sure how I should ask. The current reverses itself 5o to 60 times per sec, and this spesific reversal is what I asked. Is it suitable to write it like this?

Comment: Are you asking "why do we use AC?" "What mechanism is used to produce AC?" "Is AC better than DC?"  I"m sure if I spent more time I could come up with other specific AC-related questions.  But that is YOUR task. And be sure to search on this site for earlier questions that may have answers.

Comment: @alpy, nowadays it is impossible to not find anything you are after or want to know about in Google. It just requires you to type the keywords exactly on the search. For this case, "how is alternating current produced?" will give you thousands of links and then you choose which one to believe more in by seeing the links that end up with ".edu" There are other more professional links related to concepts that would possibly be too much to know.

Comment: Because it is forced by an alternating potential (or voltage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way alternating current is produced in wind/steam turbines, flowing water and... is that there is a *relative rotational* motion between a loop of a *conductor* and a source of *magnetic field.* Through the spinning of one inside the other, there will be an *induced electric field* and hence *current* along the wire. In the case of conductor spinning inside a magnet, the alternating nature of the induced current could be attributed to the fact that as the wire spins it enters a *different* magnetic polarity *periodically*. (namely every half a rotation the polarity of the magnet as seen by the wire is changing.) And by *Lenz's law*, this causes a change in the direction of the *induced electric field.* The details can be found in the following source too:

[Faraday's Law AND Lenz's Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/farlaw.html)